# SSL gRPC client works fine in C#, but fails with UNAVAILABLE "Empty update" in C++

Tags: c#, c++, ssl, grpc

On Windows 10 Pro 21H2 with VS2022 17.1.2 and .NET 6, I am porting a simple C# gRPC client to C++, but the C++ client always fails to connect to the server despite my code seemingly doing the same, and I ran out of ideas why.

My gRPC server is using SSL with a LetsEncrypt generated certificate (through LettuceEncrypt), thus I use default `SslCredentials`.

In C# (with `Grpc.Core`), I use gRPC as follows:

```cs
// Channel and client creation
var channel = new Channel("my.domain.org:12345", new SslCredentials());
var client = new MyGrpc.MyGrpcClient(channel);
```

```cs
// Sample call
LoginUserReply reply = client.LoginUser(new LoginUserRequest()
{
    Username = username
});
```

I converted this to C++ as follows, mostly based on examples given on the gRPC website:

```cpp
// Channel and client creation
auto channelCreds = SslCredentials(SslCredentialsOptions());
auto channel = CreateChannel("my.domain.org:12345", channelCreds);
auto stub = MyGrpc::NewStub(channel);
```

```cpp
// Sample call
ClientContext context;
LoginUserRequest request;
request.set_username(username);
LoginUserReply reply;
Status status = m_stub->LoginUser(&context, request, &reply);
```

However, with the code like this in C++, `status` always reports failure with *UNAVAILABLE (14) "Empty update"*.

**Why is that the case, and how can I fix this?**

---

Investigation I did so far:

- Using only `InsecureChannelCredentials()` results in *UNAVAILABLE (14) "failed to connect to all addresses"*.
- Running the server in plain-text, the call *does* work with *OK (0)* for testing purposes only (suggested by Lei Yang).
- I set `GRPC_TRACE=all` and `GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG` environment variables, but saw no extra logging from the client.
- In the C# server, I set the Grpc logging level to Debug, and only noticed getting no "Reading message" log line as with working / unencrypted clients.

Comment: i'm not familiar with c++, but as a debugging option, can you change your server to plain text(no tls), and make sure client working. then consider tls.

Comment: it is mentioned in the doc that there are 2 types of credentials and one of them is call credentials (`Call credentials, which are attached to a call (or ClientContext in C++)`). So check [this function](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_context.html#a06b1dfa748ef79990254787dd94f59d7), and try to set your credentials to the ClientContext, then call the rpc endpoint. I agree that the `CompositeChannelCredentials` should also work, i'm just trying to provide an alternative.

Comment: @LeiYang Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed unencrypted works, but not ringing any bell for me how to fix the encrypted communication.

Comment: @ClémentJean Thanks for the idea. I tried this, but it didn't change the outcome. I also ruled out call credentials as the source of the problem by now and removed them from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25167) in the Windows C++ implementation of the gRPC client (and apparently macOS too). There is a small note on the [gRPC authentication guide](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/#using-client-side-ssltls) stating:

> Non-POSIX-compliant systems (such as Windows) need to specify the root certificates in SslCredentialsOptions, since the defaults are only configured for POSIX filesystems.

So, to implement this on Windows, you populate `SslCredentialsOptions` as follows:

```cpp
#include <wincrypt.h>

SslCredentialsOptions getSslOptions()
{
    // Fetch root certificate as required on Windows (s. issue 25533).
    SslCredentialsOptions result;

    // Open root certificate store.
    HANDLE hRootCertStore = CertOpenSystemStoreW(NULL, L"ROOT");
    if (!hRootCertStore)
        return result;

    // Get all root certificates.
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCert = NULL;
    while ((pCert = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(hRootCertStore, pCert)) != NULL)
    {
        // Append this certificate in PEM formatted data.
        DWORD size = 0;
        CryptBinaryToStringW(pCert->pbCertEncoded, pCert->cbCertEncoded,
            CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, NULL, &size);
        std::vector<WCHAR> pem(size);
        CryptBinaryToStringW(pCert->pbCertEncoded, pCert->cbCertEncoded,
            CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER, pem.data(), &size);

        result.pem_root_certs += utf8Encode(pem.data());
    }

    CertCloseStore(hRootCertStore, 0);
    return result;
}
```

And if you need the `utf8Encode` method too:

```cpp
std::string utf8Encode(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty())
        return string();

    int sizeNeeded = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(),
        NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo(sizeNeeded, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(),
        &strTo[0], sizeNeeded, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}
```

There is a (sadly constantly staling) [feature request](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25533) on the gRPC repository to add out-of-the-box support for this on Windows aswell to make the behavior of default `SslCredentials()` the same on all systems.